# Converting JSON array response to array in Java to display buttons in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have the following JSON response from my webservices

```
{"error":"false","subjects":[{"subject":"1. Finance"},{"subject":"2. Eco"},{"subject":"3. Comm"},{"subject":"4. MGM"},{"subject":"5.  Basic Computer Skills"},{"subject":"6. Buss Env"},{"subject":"7. Intro to finances"}]}
```

I would like to pick only the subjects being returned and store it in an array.

The array will then be used to populate text for a list of buttons I have created in my android activity which have visibility set to gone by default.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to use GSon library, which allows to parse JSON easily :

For example :

```
 public class Result {
    public boolean error;
    public ArrayList<Subject> subjects;
 }

 public class Subject {
    public String subject;
 }
```

Then, somewhere else in your code :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Result result = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, Result.class);
ArrayList<Subject> yourSubjects = result.subjects;
```

Note that Gson needs to have access to your attributes. Avoid using public, better define getters/setters.
More on Gson here :

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 0):

for your example:

```
{"error":"false","subjects":[{"subject":"1. Finance"},{"subject":"2. Eco"},{"subject":"3. Comm"},{"subject":"4. MGM"},{"subject":"5.  Basic Computer Skills"},{"subject":"6. Buss Env"},{"subject":"7. Intro to finances"}]}
```

you can do it with a JSONArray:

```
JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json_you_got);
JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("subjects");
```

this returns the array object.

Then you can iterate like this:

```
int len = the_json_array.length();
ArrayList<JSONObject> arrays = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);

    arrays.add(another_json_object);
}


JSONObject[] jsons = new JSONObject[arrays.size()];
arrays.toArray(jsons);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)  and [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html):

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray subjects = data.getJSONArray("subjects");
String[] subjectsArray = new String[subjects.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < subjects.length(); i++){
     subjectsArray[i] = subjects.getString("subject");
}
```